# Uncaught ReferenceError: sel is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

**Whenever I click on div it gives me error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sel is not defined     at HTMLDivElement.onclick'**
I'm currently working on angular 8. And it gives me this error. I saw some same error related posts, but no one is really solving my issue

> Any help would be very much appreciated Thank You!

**My HTML Code**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    </div>
```

**My TS CODE**

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'samarsolprac';

  constructor() { }

 sel(id) {
    var divs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length; i++) {
        if(divs[i]!=id) {
            divs[i].className='items';
        }
    }
    id.className= 'selitem';
}

    ngOnInit() {
    }


}
```

**My CSS Code**

```js
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'samarsolprac';

  constructor() { }

 sel(id) {
    var divs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length; i++) {
        if(divs[i]!=id) {
            divs[i].className='items';
        }
    }
    id.className= 'selitem';
}

    ngOnInit() {
    }


}
```

```css
.items
{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.items:hover
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
/* css for selected div*/
.selitem
{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    <div class="items" onclick="sel(this)">one</div>
    </div>
```

```
.items
{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.items:hover
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
/* css for selected div*/
.selitem
{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <div id="container">
        <div class="items" (click)="sel(this)">one</div>
        ...
    </div>
```

In this situation **this** refers to component itself

So you can do this:

**typescript:**

```
  public sel(event): void {
    const divs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i] !== event.target) {
        divs[i].className = 'items';
      }
    }
    event.target.className = 'selitem';
  }
```

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
  <div class="items" (click)="sel($event)">one</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(click)` instead of `onclick` as below

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="items" (click)="sel(this)">one</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I Changed it from onclick to (click). It solved the previous error. But it's not changing the color of 'div' when clicked which I'm desired to do

Comment: This seems to be another issue, you could write another question to have more people trying to fix this particular issue. In this question you wanted to resolve the error from the click event. I suggest you to write a second question so and I try to fix it also.

Comment: Ok Sure Thank You